# will my laptop run 2 external (2560 x 1440) monitors @ 1080p?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I want to get 2 external monitors for my laptop :

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dell-U2515H-25-Inch-Monitor-2560/dp/B00P6O3YYO/ref=cm_cd_al_qh_dp_t

I went for the above 2560 x 1440 resolution to future proof myself.  I don't want full 2560 x 1440.  1920 x 1080p will do but will they run at 1920 x 1080 ? Im using a USB 3.0 Dual Display Docking Station to connect them.

Laptop is HP Pavilion DV6 6053ea.

AMD Radeon HD 7400M Series
Intel HD Graphics 3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AMD data sheet](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/notebook/7400m#) states that using AMD Eyefinity that it can support up to 4 displays.

It also states:

```
Dual-link DVI with HDCP

    Max resolution: 2560x1600 

DisplayPort 1.2

    Max resolution: 2560x1600
```

So you should be fine running 1080p on 2 monitors. I'm assuming the docking stations has DVI ports. Even if the DVI ports are single link you should be fine running 1080p resolution as single link [supports up to 1080p](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface).